# Creating string permutations to vary between O and 0

Tags: vb.net

Lets say i have a string that varies in size and is "OOOO". I need the below code to also return "O0O0, 0O0O, 0OO0, O00O, O000, OO00, OOO0". Basically all possible variations of O replaced with 0. What's the best way to do this? Currently it only returns "0OOO, 00OO, 000O, 0000"

```
Public Function ParseOs(ByVal PlayerName As String) As String()
    Dim NameChar As Char
    Dim OCount As Integer
    Dim OCountTwo As Integer

    For i = 0 To PlayerName.Length - 1
        NameChar = PlayerName.Chars(i)
        If NameChar = "O" Then
            OCount += 1
        End If
    Next

    Dim NewPlayerName() As String = New String(OCount - 1) {}

    For y = 0 To PlayerName.Length - 1
        NameChar = PlayerName.Chars(y)
        If NameChar = "O" Then
            NewPlayerName(OCountTwo) = PlayerName.Remove(y, 1).Insert(y, "0")
            PlayerName = NewPlayerName(OCountTwo)
            OCountTwo += 1
        End If
    Next

    Return NewPlayerName
End Function
```

Comment: What you're wanting to do is generate permutations. It's for C#, but this article might help. https://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/ It starts out different than what you're doing, but it's laying conceptual groundwork and will eventually get around to nitty gritty implementation.

Comment: Your NewPlayerName array length is wrong, it will be 2^OCount. Since there are only 2 possible characters, its like counting in binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is via recursion:

```
Public Iterator Function ParseOs(ByVal PlayerName As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)            
   Dim i as Integer = PlayerName.IndexOf("O")    
   If i = -1 Then
       Yield Return PlayerName
       Yield Break
   End If

   'Keep everything (if anything) *before* the O
   Dim base As String = PlayerName.SubString(0, i)

   Dim permutations As IEnumerable(Of String) = New String() {""}
   If PlayerName.Length > i Then
       'Recurse to find all the variations for everything *after* the O
       permutations = ParseOs(PlayerName.SubString(i+1))
   End If

   For Each permutation As String in permutations
        Yield Return base & "O" & permutation
        Yield Return base & "0" & permutation
   Next
End Function
```

If you are **sure** the inputs will always be all Os, you can simplify further:

```
Public Iterator Function ParseOs(ByVal PlayerName As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)            
   Dim permutations As IEnumerable(Of String) = New String() {""}
   If PlayerName.Length > 1 Then
       permutations = ParseOs(PlayerName.SubString(1))
   End If

   For Each permutation As String in permutations
        Yield Return "O" & permutation
        Yield Return "0" & permutation
   Next
End Function
```

You can make these more efficient by breaking it into two functions, where the recursive part deals with character arrays rather than strings. And then you can further make *that* more efficient by converting the arrays to use `Span<Char>`, so you don't have to allocate a new array for each recursive call.

Comment: The input will have other chars that are not Os, so the first solution you posted works exactly how i need it to. For example "TODOORNOTTODO" can be a input.